# .NET Core, randomly creating duplicate records

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a code-first web application made using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core 2.1.
When I save data sometimes it saves properly with only 1 record. However sometimes it saves 2 duplicated records with different Ids.

The `Create(company)` method is called only once from the controller, but sometimes creates two companies.

Controller implementation:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class CompaniesController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly ICompanyManager _companyManager;

   public CompaniesController(IEmpresaManager companyManager)
   {
       _companyManager = companyManager;
   } 

   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CompanyBindingModel companyViewModel)
   {
       try
       {
           await _companyManager.Create(_mapper.Map<Company>(companyViewModel));
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          return Conflict(ex.Message);
       }

       return Ok(new { Mensagem = "Company created successfully" });
   }
```

Manager implementation:

```cs
public class CompanyManager : ICompanyManager 
{
   private readonly RepositoyBase<Company, long> _repository;

   public CompanyManager (RepositoyBase<Company, long> repository) {
      _repository = repository;
   }

   public async Task<long> Create(Company company)
   {
      _repository.Add(company);
      await _repository.SaveChangesAsync();
      return company.Id;
   }
}
```

This is my repository pattern implementation, which saves all entities.
DbContext is injected via dependency injection and registred as scoped.

In Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddScoped<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Repository implementation

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Repositories
{
    public class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
        where TKey : struct
    {
        protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;

        public RepositoryBase(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
        }

        public virtual async Task<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(expression);
        }

        public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetById(TKey id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
        }

        public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (_dbContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                _dbContext.Attach(entity);
            }

            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Remove(TKey id)
        {
            TEntity entityToRemove = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);

            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entityToRemove);
        }

        public virtual async Task SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this caused by my repository implementation, DbContext registered as scoped or something with thread-safe?

Comment: How frequently does this occur?  Can you put a breakpoint on your Add method and watch the call stack to see where the second call is coming from?

Comment: When you're working with dbContexts, it's generally best practice to have `using` statements. It might be a good place to start (for example: `using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext()) {  //db operations here   }`     That's a good way to ensure thread safety as well. As long as each thread is using its own `dbContext` it'll prevent problems with different threads trying to do database operations.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to use using statement In web applications? Lifetime of objects are managed by framework so if you'll dispose it too early won't other calls throw an exception?

Comment: @Dortimer: Question is about ASP.NET Core, the DbContext is injected via dependency injection and valid for the duration of the request. Its **NOT** recommended to dispose a DbContexts in your code manually, unless you did instantiated it yourself (`new`ing) or you resolve it as transient and know its not used after that. Being per request scope life time it is thread safe within the request (unless you try to do parallel calls to it w/o awaiting the first result, it throws)

Comment: @hentaiLord The idea is to have a `using` statement in each of the functions of the repository. Since they're in async functions there's a strong possibility of non-thread-safe operations occurring. @tseng DbContext implements IDisposable for a reason. You don't want a context open for any longer than it needs to be, and with the pattern in the question it'll be alive for longer than the request.

Comment: @Dortimer The ASP.NET Core dependency injection engine handles disposing the DataContext. It's registered as a Scoped service, so if it's manually disposed in application code, another piece of code executing in the same request may find itself trying to use a disposed object.

Comment: @André Are you absolutely positive that the API endpoint is only being hit once? From the code you've posted, it appears the most likely culprit is that something is making two requests to the same endpoint.

Comment: @Dortimer: That is *categorically* wrong. You should in fact virtually *never* use a `using` statement with a context. The context should be request-scoped. The only time you might use a `using` is in maybe the context of a console application and only then when creating it in `Main`. Any subsequent usage should be passed that instance.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That's a really terrible idea if you plan on doing literally any asynchronous operations. Using a single context for all threads is guaranteed to break down if you ever try to have different threads do any db operations. I'm saying the `Create` function should be added to include `Add()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` together, not in separate functions. Having a class-wide scoped context like this is dangerous, and the context is far from request-scoped in this instance.

Comment: @Dortimer: That's just not correct. What you're talking about is concurrency, which is only tangentially related to async. As I said, the context should be request-scoped, which is roughly equivalent to saying it should be *thread*-scoped. Even if there's a context switch, there's still going to be just one thread working on that context instance. If you're trying to do things in parallel within a single scope, that's a different story of course, but that's not the norm.

Comment: @Dortimer: The `using`/Dispose recommendations come from console and desktop applications. There scopes usually don't exist there (or are singleton/transient) and having a long-lived dbcontext could lead to memory leaks (EF's tracker keeping to track huge amount of entities can slow it down and consume considerable amount of memory). Its not valid for ASP.NET Core (or even ASP.NET when using an DI/IoC container which manages it per request scope)

Comment: Any chance to your front end javascript code calling this endpoint twice? Can you reproduce the error using swagger or postman?

Comment: For your current implementation, it would not insert two duplicate records if you did not call twice with the same `CompanyBindingModel`. In general, we may difine the unique property to indicate whether the records is unique. You may consider define a name property in `CompanyBindingModel ` and check it before inserting it to database to avoide duplicate name records.